# Include Piwik in a website via an iframe

Tags: php, html, matomo

So I have an admin panel, and I want to include Piwik via an iframe which I host on a subdomain, I have tried `<iframe src="http://domain.domain.me" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>`

But it doesn't work. It gives me a blank page. I think it has some sort of protection, do you know if it's possible to find a workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in the doc
[Piwik doc](http://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because the link points straight to the point and you just started giving answers, but including some quotes (if not forbidden to quote by licence etc) and an explanation is what makes the answer really worth upvoting.

Comment: I'm pretty new here. thank you for the advice I'll be more careful now.